# No notification sent when posting to page feed using Facebook php SDK 4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a post to a page (On a users behalf ) and the post does show in the feed but there is no notification to the page owner (not necessarily the user who's posting ) that a new post has been made.

here is what the function looks like

```
global $fb_app_id;
global $fb_app_key; 

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $fb_app_id, $fb_app_key );

$session = new FacebookSession(custom_facebook_getToken($user_id));

if ( isset( $session ) ) {
$request = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/PAGEIDHERE/feed', array(
'link' => 'www.somesite.com',
'message' => 'website Coming Soon.....',
//picture – URL of an image you want to include in the update
//name - The name of the link attachment
//caption - The caption of the link (appears beneath the link name)
//description - The description of the link (appears beneath the link caption)
)))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
}
```

Comment: does the post work?.. what is the response?..

Comment: Yeah Post shows up on Facebook, responce is the post id   (["signedRequestData":"Facebook\FacebookSession":private]=> NULL } array(1) { ["id"]=> string(33) "299683480205228_10152277756267362" })

Comment: if you're sure a notification should be sent, i suggest opening a bug on developers.facebook.com.  it does not appear to be SDK related, as it did create the post.

Comment: Actually i am not sure but assume that a notification should be sent as it does if the user makes the post manually. I tried searching all over to no avail and i cant find any info on this issue.